# Why doesn't Microsoft release a 'proper' AJAX grid for ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Why doesn't Microsoft release a 'proper' AJAX grid for ASP.Net either as part of Visual Studio or the AJAX control toolkit? Has there been any discussion that anyone is aware of regarding this issue?

Also does anyone have any open source suggestions for 'proper' AJAX gridviews?

So far I have found one....

http://dotnetslackers.com/projects/AjaxDataControls/Default.aspx

PS: By proper I mean a grid that actually uses XML responses rather than the nasty html javascript based injection that is the current nastyness of the gridview (EVEN IN VS 2010).

Comment:

> Sorry this. __curious_geek but although I understand your argument I do not accept that answer. My (quick) response to you would boil down to, A: ASP.Net and its controls are a high level framework and not a low level API per se (I know this can be argued but you get my point) B: Databinding is an extensive part of said framework C: Given that databinding is an extensive part of the framework, surely Microsoft in its infinite wisdom would like to implement the most efficient solution (and surely it couldn’t be argued that the current implementation is optimal). D: Most importantly this is not a specialized problem but rather a highly generic one....

Answer (score 0):

Webforms developers generally doesn't care about that stuff. Most developers that do, use some other framework (like asp.net mvc for example). There are so many things in webforms that is "nasty", like viewstate and post backs for example. My guess is that they simply doesn't see any reason to do so.

Comment: I agree MVC is probably the way to go but we still need to support legacy applications and to suggest that webforms developers don’t care about that is wrong.. .

Comment: @Maxim Gershkovich, I would guess that 99% of the webforms developers doesn't care about it. There have always been alternatives to webforms, and even if you use webforms you don't have to use server controls. If it where me I would simply write the ajax call myself using jquery as I find that a lot easier then using some built-in-control.

Answer (score 0):

Because..

**http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2003/10/28/53298.aspx**